EXCEL VBA : Wrap Cell Text at certain Location
This is sample data :



Item




Item#1 * ItemName_1


Item#2 * ItemName_2



I need to wrap text at the "*" like this
Item#1
ItemName_1

Item#2
ItemName_2
This is what i tryed after browsing Stackoverflow and others :
Sub BreakAndWrap()    
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A250").End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "*", ChrW(8209))
    cell.WrapText = True
Next

End Sub
This Replaces "*" by "-" and wrap but manually and at randome location not at hyphen.

Insert a line feed (vbCrLf) where you want the break

Replace it with the Chr(10) character.
Sub BreakAndWrap()    
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A250").End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "*", Chr(10))
    cell.WrapText = True
Next
End Sub

ChrW(8209) is the non-breaking hyphen.


Don't need to use For loop

Sub BreakAndWrap()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A250").End(xlUp))
    rng.Replace What:=" * ", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub


Ok, it is working but when ItemName_1 or ItemName_2 is multi Text it breaks and wrap at each space. Could you fix this make the break and wrap at the "*" only? Thanks

Please show sample data.
